# Is there Terraform script for creating migration activity in Azure?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have created Azure data migration service and migration project using terraform, so is there any terraform scripts available for creating migration activity in Azure?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

***Currently its not possible with Terraform*** as only ***Database Migration Service and Project are available*** for now . You can use ***[`ARM template`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datamigration/services/projects/tasks?tabs=bicep)*** for the same .

If you want to use Terraform , then you can use [***`local-exec`***](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) to use PowerShell or CLI and execute the ***[`Az-powershell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/howto-sql-server-to-azure-sql-powershell)*** or ***[`Az CLI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/dms/project/task?view=azure-cli-latest#az-dms-project-task-create)*** commands there .

***Example of Local-exec :***

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<Settings
    $ResourceGroupName = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
    $FunctionAppName = "${var.function_app}"
    $SubscriptionId = "${var.Subscription}"
    Get-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionAppName -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId
    Settings

interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, i will try this